# Can my iPad app access a list of the eBooks on the device?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sandbox

I have a little experience with iPhone development but am new to iPad. I realize that apps are sandboxed and cannot access each other's data, but is there any way that the iPad app can access information about the eBooks on the iPad--for instance, the titles and authors of these books?

Answer (score 1):

No, not with the current SDK.